# WGS1984 polygon labels incorrectly located in web mercator projection?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, coordinate-system

I have polygons for states/provinces (wgs1984). When I label these polygons in ArcGIS (web mercator) some of the labels occur in random locations. For example, texas might show up in southern canada, while ontario and quebec will show up in virginia. Any suggestions?

Comment: your tag states arc 10, please check the recent post here, to see if there are any suggestions that might help you. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3593/why-are-my-labels-in-the-wrong-polygons

Comment: thank you. I had previously read this article and tries all of the suggestions. I am currently attempting to source a maplex license to use with my EDN subscription to try and fix the rendering with Maplex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an update: 
Using the maplex labeling engine fixed this behavior. It would seem that if labels originally were created with maplex, then attempting to render them with the standard engine can cause these types of issue.